# how to solve the following integral (maybe by integration by parts)?

Tags: integration

Could you please help me solve this integral?
I already have the answer but I don't understand it. I know that I can use integration by parts. But I can't make sense of it.
$$
g = \int_{1}^{\infty} (t-1)^j e^{-t^2} dt
$$

Comment: Is the integral with respect to $t$? It looks like you forgot $dt$ but I want to make sure.

Comment: thanks @AdamRubinson I added dt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $j$ is a positive integer.

Hints: Call the integral $I(j)$. Then $$I(j)=\int_1^{\infty} (t-1) (t-1)^{j-1} e^{-t^{2}} dt$$ $$=\int_1^{\infty} t(t-1)^{j-1} e^{-t^{2}} dt-\int_1^{\infty}  (t-1)^{j-1} e^{-t^{2}} dt$$ The second term is $I(j-1)$. In the first term write $te^{-t^{2}}$ as the derivative of $-\frac 1  2 e^{-t^{2}}$  and integrate by parts. This term becomes $-\frac 1  2 e^{-t^{2}}(t-1)^{j-1}|_1^{\infty} +(j-1)\frac 1  2 \int_1^{\infty}(t-1)^{j-2}e^{-t^{2}}dt$. Now you get a recurrence relation and you have to solve this to find $I(j)$.